# How to make match the progress bar circle to the background?

Tags: android, xml, android-progressbar

I'd like to create a progress bar with a white background, and I've (I think) found the solution by creating a drawable in the shape of a circle for the parent containing the progress bar. However, I'd like the two circles to match perfectly, and this for any screen type (so no dp).
[my page with the progress bar smaller than the white background](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uY1Rc.png)

Try as I might, I just can't seem to get rid of this problem. I've tried having the progress bar at 110% of its size to try and fix the problem, but it doesn't work. I've also tried changing the drawable, but again it doesn't work...

fragment_calendar.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/calendar"
    tools:context=".CalendarFragment">

    <com.airbnb.lottie.LottieAnimationView
        android:id="@+id/lottieAnimationView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        app:lottie_autoPlay="true"
        app:lottie_loop="true"
        app:lottie_rawRes="@raw/plant_bg"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="0dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="-162dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/welcomeBackTitle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/default_welcome_calendar"
        android:textSize="32sp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.100"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.15"
        />

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        android:background="@drawable/circle_white_bg"
        app:layout_constraintWidth_default="percent"
        app:layout_constraintWidth_percent="0.9"
        app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="1:1"
        >
        <ProgressBar
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:indeterminate="false"
            android:max="10"
            android:progress="10"
            android:rotation="160"
            style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.ProgressBar.Horizontal"
            android:background="@drawable/gray_progressbar_bg"
            android:progressDrawable="@drawable/gradient_progressbar_bg"
            />
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:gravity="center">
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/currentTaskTitle"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/current_task_calendar_title"
                android:textSize="30sp"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:layout_gravity="center"/>
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/currentTaskName"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="NAME OF THE CURRENT TASK"
                android:textColor="@color/dark_blue"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:layout_marginHorizontal="40dp"
                android:textSize="24sp" />
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/currentTaskTimer"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/default_current_task_time"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:textColor="@color/dark_blue"
                android:textSize="24sp" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </FrameLayout>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

circle_white_bg.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape android:shape="oval" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <size android:width="50dp" android:height="50dp" />
    <solid
        android:color="@color/white"/>
</shape>
```

gradient_progress_bar.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item>
    <shape android:shape="ring"
        android:innerRadiusRatio="2.5"
        android:thicknessRatio="30.0"
        android:useLevel="true">
        <gradient
            android:startColor="@color/dark_blue"
            android:centerColor="@color/dark_blue_lighter"
            android:endColor="@color/sky_blue"/>
    </shape>
</item>
</layer-list>
```

thank you for your reply!